# Angular, @Injectable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a service like this

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export default class UserService {
   ...
}
```

and use it inside component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.css']
})
export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private userService: UserService) { }
  ...
}
```

Each time, when I change something in the code and it re-built, I see an error

```
main.ts:12 ReferenceError: UserService is not defined
```

What I miss? Is it incorrect implementation?

I am using Angular 11.2.
My dev env inside docker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `default` from `export default class UserService`